# GridView LinqDataSource and Calendar controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, linqdatasource

This is seemingly easy task and yet I can't get this to worl so please give me your pointers. I have a `SQL` table that has one of its columns of `DateTime` type. I want to access it from `ASP` application via `LinqDataSource`. I want to provide `WHERE` parameter to `LinqDataSource`from `Calendarcontrol` (that returns `DateTime` as SelectedDate). I want to display set in `GridView`. Seems easy, doesn't it? But regardless of what I do I get an error at runtime:

> Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type `DateTime` and Object
>   which makes no sense to me because Calendar returns `DateTime` and `LINQ` class also returns `DateTime` for that column.
>   How would you approach this task or this problem. I can't use `SqlDataSource` because of `SQL` served and `IIS` security configuration that currently I do not want to touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly it is impossible to perform this wiring declaratively. Instead load your query with filters into a List<>)_ and bind GridView to it in C# code.